# How to wrap long results from grep

Tags: bash, word-wrap, uniq

Kindly excuse my ignorance. I'm a novice in Unix. This might sound silly.
I'm running the below command on a file that contains some log details.

> cat ./Logfile | uniq -c

Now, when the file contains extra long lines that goes beyond the screen width, it creates a horizontal scrollbar for the user on the text viewer.

Is there someway I can wrap the text to the next line so that the results looks legible and scroll friendly for the user? Something that looks like below.

```
23  This is just a sample result text that has come up to be very long but was 
    WRAPPED to the next line so that the results are displayed in a scroll fri
    endly format. Is that really possible?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `fold` utility, e.g.:

```
$ cat text
This is just a sample result text that has come up to be very long but was WRAPPED to the next line so that the results are displayed in a scroll friendly format. Is that really possible?

$ fold -s -w 80 text
This is just a sample result text that has come up to be very long but was
WRAPPED to the next line so that the results are displayed in a scroll friendly
format. Is that really possible?
```

Comment: I've used this before but it doesn't help my requirement. Since fold splits long lines into separate parts, a uniq -c looses its purpose. It ends up in fetching unique lines that are totally split. What I'm trying to achieve is to wrap the text results of "cat text | uniq -c"

Comment: I believe you are just piping in the wrong order, you need to apply the `fold` as the last command in your pipe, e.g. `uniq -c ./Logfile | fold -s -w 80` (`cat` is not needed, btw.).

Answer (score 1):

What terminal you are using? Where do you see these scrollbars?

Typically the output should wrap as you expect, except that wrapped line starts from the beginning of line rather than is aligned, so I would expect you get the following output from your command:

```
 23  This is just a sample result text that has come up to be very long but was 
WRAPPED to the next line so that the results are displayed in a scroll fri
endly format. Is that really possible?
```

Edit:
Thanks for clarification, now I understand your case.
I think you could use this fold as others suggest here, but pipe it AFTER uniq:

```
cat ./Logfile | uniq -c | fold -s -w 80 > result.txt
```

Comment: I'm not facing this on the terminal. I'm directing the output to a text file for reporting purposes. So when the text file opens up, the contents are no wrapped. Of course, I can use the wrap option in the text pad, but the requirement is particular about limiting the number of characters in a line to a fixed number and start the next line with a right justification such that it looks like a table layout.

Comment: I think `fold` suggested by Adrian should do the trick here, but you need to pipe commands in right order. I've edited my answer with example.

Comment: I think you are spot on there, I didn't consider that the OP might pipe in the "wrong" order.